mariabackup mysqld got signal 11
i got error when i take full backup of my mariadb 10.5 database:
mariabackup --host=$DB_HOST --port=$DB_PORT --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD --backup --target-dir=$RESTIC_PATH

logs:
[01] 2024-04-29 16:27:50 Copying ./dbname/userSuspendLogs.frm to /db/dbname/userSuspendLogs.frm
[01] 2024-04-29 16:27:50         ...done
[00] 2024-04-29 16:27:50 Finished backing up non-InnoDB tables and files
240429 16:27:50 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
Sorry, we probably made a mistake, and this is a bug.

Your assistance in bug reporting will enable us to fix this for the next release.
To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.5.23-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 source revision: 6cfd2ba397b0ca689d8ff1bdb9fc4a4dc516a5eb
key_buffer_size=0
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 6067 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
Printing to addr2line failed
mariabackup(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x5615e265385e]
mariabackup(handle_fatal_signal+0x475)[0x5615e21bd2c5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x13140)[0x7ff1ed173140]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(opendir+0x0)[0x7ff1ecd35d10]
mariabackup(+0x6d1378)[0x5615e1e6a378]
mariabackup(_Z12backup_startP7ds_ctxtS0_R14CorruptedPages+0x10b)[0x5615e1e6d5fb]
mariabackup(+0x6bf67b)[0x5615e1e5867b]
mariabackup(main+0x17e)[0x5615e1e0f54e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xea)[0x7ff1ecc96d0a]
mariabackup(_start+0x2a)[0x5615e1e4566a]
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mariadbd/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       514893               514893               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: core

Kernel version: Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07)

/m.entrypoint.sh: line 15:     8 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) mariabackup --host=$DB_HOST --port=$DB_PORT --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD --backup --target-dir=$RESTIC_PATH


I have the same problem, Thanks for question

This is https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31251, a mariadb-backup bug, that will be fixed in the very soon coming next release including versions:

10.4.34
10.5.25
10.6.18
10.11.8
11.0.6
11.1.5
11.2.4
11.4.2
11.5.1

A workaround this bug is to use "--aria-log-dir-path=." as a mariabackup option.

it works for mariadb 10.5
but another database (galera+mariadb 11.2.3) error [ERROR] InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. The redo log was created with MariaDB 11.2.3.
[00] 2024-04-30 13:07:49 Error: cannot read redo log header

Run a clean shutdown on that datadir with 11.2.3, then return to the previous version.

and or are you restoring a backup without having prepared with with the same version you took the backup (11.2.3)
